# Bash Script - Find log larger than xx , if condition is met restart the service

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create  bash script which will find the log file size more than 100 MB, if it find it should delete that file and restart the service but I am not able to achieve it. Even if the condition is not meet it is restarting the service.

Script:

```
if [[ $(find /var/log/ -size +100M -name "test.log" -delete) ]]
then
echo "Found"
service restart /etc/service/service_name/
fi
```

Could someone please point me out, what I did wrong?

Comment: Add a `-print` option to the `find` command, then your script should work.

Comment: Is there a check for only 1 file: `/var/log/test.log` or many: `/var/log/**/test.log` ? Maybe `find` is not the more apropriated command!?

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `du` and `cut` would be:

```
max_size_in_bytes=12500000 # 100MB

if [ $(du -sb file.log | cut -f1) -ge $max_size_in_bytes ]; then
  echo "Found"
  service restart /etc/service/service_name/ 
fi
```

The `-ge` flag means `greater than or equal to`, you could use `-gt` just for `greater than`.

EDIT:

As F. Hauri said, `stat -c %s file.log` is better than `du -sb file.log | cut -f1`

Comment: If you only check 1 file, use `stat -c %s file.log` instead!